# Is there an equivalent of pluck() in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq

I just discovered jOOQ today and decided to give it a try. Just wondering, is there an equivalent of Eloquent's pluck().  This eliminates writing a lot of verbose code just to get a single value. e.g. in Eloquent (Laravel) I will get name of a place simply by:

```
    $name = Place::where('iso_code', '=', $code)->pluck('name');
```

or

```
    $name = DB::table('places')->where('iso_code', '=', $code)->pluck('name');
```

Is there something equivalent in jOOQ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how I understand `pluck()` (interesting naming choice), I suspect what you want to do is the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT name FROM places WHERE iso_code = ?
```

In jOOQ, the following statement will do the same (using the code generator):

```java
String name =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(PLACES.NAME)
   .from(PLACES)
   .where(PLACES.ISO_CODE.eq(code))
   .fetchOne(PLACES.NAME);
```

Without using the code generator:

```java
Field<String> field = DSL.field("name", String.class);

String name =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field)
   .from("places")
   .where("iso_code = ?", code)
   .fetchOne(field);
```

So, the equivalent of Eloquent's `pluck()` is jOOQ's [`ResultQuery.fetchOne(Field)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne-org.jooq.Field-)